# Android react-native showsMyUserLocation doesn't appear

Tags: android, react-native

I have the following code in my ./src/index.js:

```js
import React from 'react';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

import {View} from 'react-native';

const App = () => (
  <View style={{flex: 1}}>
    <MapView
      style={{flex: 1}}
      region={{
        latitude: -27.210753,
        longitude: -49.644183,
        latitudeDelta: 0.00143,
        longitudeDelta: 0.00035,
      }}
      showsUserLocation={true}
      showsMyLocationButton={true}
      loadingEnabled
    />
  </View>
);

export default App;
```

I can't see showsUserLocation, showsMyLocationButton. Otherwise, I can see map and my place with coordinates that I put.

Please, need I do something else?

Answer (score 0):

Your location of your phone is probably not turned on. If you are using android, try going into google maps on phone and check if you are able to see your location. If you are not able to see your location:

Go to More > Location. Enter your lat-long > Press SEND

Hope this helps!

Comment: I can see my location into Google Maps. I'm novice on react, but I suspect that there's some update issue associated to react-native-maps...